# How to pass two objects to use in a form using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

My problem is the following :

I've 2 differents objects that I've to fill from a single form.

With 1 object, I simply do in the newFoo.html:

```html
<form th:object="${foo}" th:action="@{/foo}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

and in the FooController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/new", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String newFoo(final Foo foo, Model model) { 
    return "newFoo"; 
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/new", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String saveFoo(final Foo foo, final BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) { 
    fooService.save(foo); 
    return "redirect:/foo/new"; 
}
```

Let's say I've an other object bar with a "status" variable in it. How can I do to pass that object so I can submit the input within the same form?

Like:

```html
<form th:object="${foo} && ${bar}" th:action="@{/foo}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{status}"/>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

So far I tried to do with to fieldset with a th:object in it, that doesn't work, I tried to put two th:object in the form, that doesn't work either.

The only way I found is to build an other object containing those two objects, and pass it. That works well, but I can't create that kind of object, it's nonsense (even if it works).

Of course, the objects aren't as simple as Foo and Bar here, otherwise I would have merge those two. But that's not something I can do.

Is it even possible to pass two objects like that to use in a form ?

Thanks already.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't think you need to use two `th:objects`. Just use `th:value`

```
<form th:action="@{/foo}" method="post">
      <input type="text" th:value="${foo.name}" name="name"/>
      <input type="text" th:value="${bar.status}" name="status"/>
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

I would think Spring is smart enough, on the controller side, to use its mapping techniques to map your fields to their proper command object, foo or bar.

Comment: I just tried that, and actually that doesn't work. All the variables of the object are null when I get them after the submit. Binding results objects are null, Model the same. Thanks anyway. Looks like Spring isn't smart enough.

Comment: Oh, it's because we didn't set a name for them. The input `name` has to match the bean field name.

Comment: Does this imply that in a Spring-Thymeleaf project, use of th:object is in general not necessary?

Comment: @MikeHT Not necessarily. `th:object` would have been useful here if, for example, there were a bunch of `foo` fields. It would make it shorter to write them all out with a simple `*{..}`.

Comment: So if you set `th:object` on the form itself, can you still use a separate `${object.attribute}` on one of the form's inputs?

Comment: Actually there might be some problems when both objects have the same field (e.g. both `foo` and `bar` have the field `name`. At controller level, they will have the same value, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

i used a div tag to surround the form input for my second object and added a th:object..... the controller processed it and added it to the database.

```
<form method=post th:object="${object1}" >
   <div th:object="${object2}" >

      code......

   </div> 
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```