# Thymeleaf - How to POST a fixed object to controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a collection of checkboxes where each one represents a topping of a 'product'. I want to pass a modified 'product' object with the checked 'toppings' stored as 'selectedToppings'.

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work. The problem is that I'm passing an empty 'product' object and only the checkbox values are stored(as 'selectedToppings'). 
How can I pass a the 'product' object along with the 'selectedToppings'?

html(fragment):

```
            <form method="post" th:object="${product}" th:action="@{/addItemToCart}">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div th:each="topping : ${product.toppings}">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" th:id="${topping} + ${product.id}" name="toppings" th:value="${topping}" />
                                <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="${topping} + ${product.id}" th:text="${topping}"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Add to Shopping Cart</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addItemToCart", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addItemToCart(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, @RequestParam("toppings") List<String> toppings)
{
    Product newItem = product;
    newItem.setSelectedToppings(toppings);
    addItemToBucket(newItem);

    return "redirect:/menu";
}
```

entity:

```
public class Product
{
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
private Double price;
private List<String> toppings;
private List<String> selectedToppings;

public Product()
{
 this.id = "";
 this.name = "";
 this.description = "";
 this.price = 0.0;
 this.toppings = new ArrayList<String>();
 this.selectedToppings = new ArrayList<String>();
}
public Product(String id, String name, String description, Double price, List<String> toppings)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.toppings = toppings;
    this.selectedToppings = new ArrayList<String>();
}
//...getters & setters
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass multiple objects to the controller. This would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122257/how-to-pass-two-objects-to-use-in-a-form-using-thymeleaf

Comment: @JaisAnkit I'm interested in passing objects to controller in the context of the question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I completely understand your question or not.

If you add following on your `<input>` tag, it should work.

`th:field="*{toppings}"`

One thing I notice now is, you are missing getter/setter for your Product class.

Comment: what are you seeing if you do product.getToppings() ? BTW does your entity class Product have getters/setter ?

Comment: The 'toppings' variable is filled correctly. But the rest of the object is empty. Yes, I have getters/setters for every variable.

Comment: Other variables will be empty as there are not any other fields beside toppings  on your form.

Comment: I've passed the 'product' as a model attribute. product.selectedToppings was the only empty variable and I wanted to get filled from the user. Is it possible?

Comment: If all you want is one parameter, why you have to map with Product class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169114/discussion-between-tony-and-want2learn).