# ModelAttribute is null after form

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to make a small climbing website as a personal project but I struggle to put value inside my modelAttribute.

```java
    @RequestMapping("/new_topo")
    public String addTopo(Model model){
        Topo topo = new Topo();
        Sector sector = new Sector();

        model.addAttribute("topo", topo);
        model.addAttribute("sector", sector);
        return "new_topo";
    }
```

As you can see, I add in my model 1 instance of Topo and Sector, where data will be received here :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add a Spot</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragment/header :: header"> </div>
<h1 align="center">Add a topo</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save_topo}" method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>cotation</td>
            <td> <input type="text" th:field ="${topo.cotation}"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sector</td>
            <td> <input type="text" th:value ="${sector.name}"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>spits_amount</td>
            <td> <input type="number" th:field ="${topo.spitAmount}"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that when I try to have access to sector's field, it says that "Sector is null" while topo's fields are received perfectly fine. This is how I check the data received :

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save_topo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTopo(@ModelAttribute("topo") Topo topo, @ModelAttribute("sector") Sector sector){
        System.out.println("============================");
        System.out.println(topo.getCotation() + " " + topo.getSpitAmount()); // Data 100% received
        System.out.println("============================");
        System.out.println("NAME IS EQUALS TO : " + sector.getName()); // null, did not receive the input from the form
        topo.getSector().add(sector);
        sector.setTopo(topo);
        topoService.save(topo);
        sService.save(sector);
        return "topos";
    }
```

note that i'm totally new in the web / back end community and that I might not know 100% of how things works (which I think will be obvious for you).

Thank you for any upcoming help !

EDIT : This might help ?

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Tue Mar 17 09:05:27 GMT 2020
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   No message available
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.lufen.Project6.lade.Controller.TopoController.saveTopo(TopoController.java:45)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this (note the `name` attribute, which should equal to the bean field names):

```
 <input type="text" th:value="${sector.name}" name="name">
```

If it doesn`t work, change the rest like this too:

```
 <input type="text" th:value="${topo.cotation}" name="cotation"> </td>

 <input type="number" th:value="${topo.spitAmount}" name="spitAmount"> </td>
```

Comment: Same, still <null> I changed it when I readed this comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122257/how-to-pass-two-objects-to-use-in-a-form-using-thymeleaf

Comment: I edited my post with new suggestion, please try again

Comment: nevermind It worked, but still a null page when I try to save the page ! (my sout détecte now the name field of sector. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

To store the values taken from input text fields in object fields we have to use `th:object="${object_name}"`  in thymeleaf.
But here there is a need to store the input values in two different objects.
We can create a class that contains fields of type both Sector and Topo.

```
public class SectorAndTopo{
      Sector sector = new Sector();
      Topo topo = new Topo();
}
```

Add the object of this class as attribute to model

```
 @RequestMapping("/new_topo")
    public String addTopo(Model model){
        SectorAndTopo sectorAndTopo = new SectorAndTopo();

        model.addAttribute("sectorAndTopo", sectorAndTopo);
        return "new_topo";
    }
```

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save_topo}" th:object="${sectorAndTopo}" method="post">
<input type="text" th:field ="*{topo.cotation}">
<input type="text" th:field ="*{sector.name}">
<input type="number" th:field ="*{topo.spitAmount}">
<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see between the one which works and which don't is attribute field and value.

Change

```
th:value ="${sector.name}"
```

To

```
th:field ="${sector.name}"
```

Comment: Gonna check it bute I think I already tried :) thank you ! EDIT: same :(